# domain of the Dirichlet Laplacian

Tags: operator-theory, laplacian

Let $s\geq 0$ be a real number, $\Omega$ bounded and smooth domain in $\mathbb R^d$. We can define the spectral power of the Dirichlet Laplacian $(-\Delta_\Omega)$ on $\Omega$. Then, on the whole space, the fractional laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ is an operator defined via Fourier transform:
$$\mathcal F((-\Delta)^s u)(\xi):= |\xi|^{2s} \mathcal F (u)(\xi)\, .$$
Then, do we have the following continuous embedding
$$\text{dom}(-\Delta_\Omega)^s\subset \text{dom}(-\Delta)^s\, ?$$

Comment: No, this fails already in simple situations. If you take $s=d=1$, $\Omega=(a,b)$, then $D(-\Delta)=H^2(\mathbb R)$, $D(-\Delta_{\Omega})=H^2_0(a,b)$, but these latter functions need not have a second derivative at $a,b$ when you extend them. (I'm assuming you identify $L^2(\Omega)$ with a subspace of $L^2(\mathbb R^d)=L^2(\Omega)\oplus L^2(\Omega^c)$ in the obvious way.)

Comment: Agreed, except that $D(-\Delta_\Omega)=H^2\cap H^1_0\neq H^2_0$ (in usual notations)...

Comment: @JeanDuchon: Yes, my notation is sloppy, $D(-\Delta_{\Omega})$ is those $H^2$ functions with $u(a)=u(b)=0$, and I guess you wouldn't normally call this $H^2_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Can we say more generally that $\text{dom}(-\Delta_\Omega)^s=H^{2s}(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: Obviously not for $s<1/2$, but otherwise yes, I think.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: Sorry. I wouldn't have added "I think" if I had one at hand...